# How can I maintain the Highcharts halo effect on pie chart after click and mouseOut?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Within the Highcharts pie chart, is there a way to maintain the halo effect on a series after clicking it and losing focus by mouseOut?  By hovering over the chart I get the hover state which produces the halo, but I'd like to be able to click it and hover away and maintain the hover effect which includes the halo.

Comment: You can manage point's state by point.setState() method. If you pass as argument 'hover' the point will enter hover state - see example http://jsfiddle.net/cLsxcL93/

Answer (score 0):

The [stickyTracking](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.stickyTracking) option does not trigger a mouseOut event until the mouse moves over another series or out of the plot area.  See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zLojqu1/) for an example.  Notice that I've added

```
stickyTracking: true,
```

to the pie options in:

```
   plotOptions: {
      pie: {
```